# How to Redirect to a Private-Use URI Scheme From a LogIn Page?

Tags: redirect, oauth-2.0, cors

I have an OAuths flow (code grant, native app) that works like so:

1. User opens a native app and clicks on a login button in it
2. User's Default web browser is lunched and navigates to `www.domain1.com/authorize`
3. User is redirected (302) to a login page at `www.domain1.com/login.html` (a react page)
4. User enters his credentials and submits
5. Login page calls `www.domain1.com/login` on submit
6. If the credentials are correct then the login page gets a redirect (302) to `com.mycompany.app://callback` as a response to the call to `www.domain1.com/login`
7. Browser follows redirect (302) to `com.mycompany.app://callback`

Now, I expected the native app associated with the private URI scheme `com.mycompany.app://callback` to get the callback and open. However, what actually happens is that the browser returns an error (this one is in chrome, in Firefox and Safari the message is a bit different but same meaning):

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted
```

I saw a not-so-similar issues with trying to access a local file `file://` but the situation I have is different. Also, I have no option to add 'http' or 'https' since this will cause the redirect to navigate to a web address and not to a local private URI.

Anyone know why is that? how can I get rid of the error and get the desired behavior?